# How to Convert a negative value received through a parameter to positive in the stored procedure code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have some concerns, I'm creating a stored procedure to work with a cafeteria system. The user on the cafeteria will send me through parameter an employee code and the amount consumed. So I far I have calculated this:

IF @Amount< @Subsidy  (Subsidy being 20 Dollars per day)

```
BEGIN

 UPDATE CreditSub 
   SET Subsidy = Subsidy - @Amount, Fecha = @CurrDate   
  WHERE Code = @Code;

END


 IF @Amount > @Subsidy (Being credit 100)

 BEGIN  

   UPDATE CreditSub 
   SET @AmountDif= @Amount - Subsidy, Subsidy= 0, Credit = Credit - @AmountDif,                Date = @CurrDate
   WHERE Code = @Code;

 END
```

What I'm basically doing is a calculation that if the user insert less than 20 dollars it will run the first batch if is greater it's going to run the second deducting the 20 dollars of the subsidy plus deducting the rest of the credit (being 100 Dollars).

Now, if the user cancels the order, the value returned to me will be a negative value like "If the employee orders 70 dollars of food, then the order must be cancelled, the system will return -70 which I need to take and summarize part of it to the subsidy and part of it to the credit if the subsidy was not spent on that day. How do I split the values or rollback the last transaction converting the negative to positive?. Please ask me any questions, I need help here with this.

Thanks a billion!

Comment: My initial thought is that there should be a `TransactionType` column in the `CreditSub` table.  Transaction types could be anything appropriate for your business rules: credit, debit, refund, void, etc.  For certain transaction types, you might need to know the record for the original transaction.  So there would be a `ReferenceId` column that is a foreign key to `CreditSubId`.  Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi @DMason, thanks for the suggestion and that's great but, there's another table not mentioned here that manages all of the transaction in case one needs to be cancelled etc. This table only handles the Credit and Subsidy, once the order has been cancelled I must return to the original value. If the values were : Subsidy = 20 and Credit = 100, someone uses 70, then it will be : Subsidy = 0 Credit = 50. If the order got cancelled I must return everything back to normal. That's what Im missing

Comment: Ok, so the other table keeps track of transactions (including history) and `CreditSub` is for running totals?

Comment: CreditSub is basically to control the Credit and Subsidy as the name says. I will keep the balance updated each day and it must reset daily back to normal. The subsidy is given by the company for free, the credit must be paid by the employee at the end of the month. So those values will be inserted into another table at the end of the day to keep track.

Comment: The "Subsidy = 20 and Credit = 100, someone uses 70" example would be pretty easy to revert to original state.  But I can see where this gets complicated.  For instance, someone has two CreditSub records (orders?) and then they cancel one of them.  I think this leads back to my original suggestion, which involves making each order(?) an insert--no updates.  But it sounds like this is not in line with the data architecture.  I'm not sure how much more I can add...

Comment: @DMason I totally understand that this may be kind of hard to understand from any other than me right now. The order can be cancelled just right after being submitted. I will think of a better explanation. Thank you

Comment: What if you broke out `CreditSub` into two tables by @Code?  The `Credit` table could track the credit amount throughout the day--positive or negative wouldn't matter, right?  The `Subsidy` table would be populated once per day (or as needed) with the subsidy amount.  Then at the end of the day, you can do the math when you populate your other table.  If you need to know what the current subsidy amount is, just join the two tables and perform the necessary calculation to get the amount.

Comment: @DMason sounds like a good idea man, thank you for sharing this with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break out `CreditSub` into two tables by @Code. The `Credit` table will track the credit amount throughout the day--positive or negative won't matter. The `Subsidy` table would be populated once per day (or as needed) with the subsidy amount. Then at the end of the day, you can do the math when you populate your other table. If you need to know what the current subsidy amount is, just join the two tables and perform the necessary calculation to get the amount.